# Extra starting equipment not bought using starting gold

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

I have a player making a level 1 half-elf/half-dwarf blood hunter using the starting equipment packs who insists that his character can start out with 3 martial weapons (2 scimitars and a rapier) instead of the suggested 2 simple or 1 martial weapon.

However, the character has a sage background and all the abilities and starting gold associated with it. His argument is that as a blood hunter he can pick the two-weapon fighting style at level 2 and the character can afford it because he's from a noble family, so it's really not a big deal if he starts out with these weapons.

My concern is that the character is already pretty op with bonuses from being both an elf and a dwarf, but it's hard to enforce any rules since I'm a new DM (this is my first game) and he has a lot of experience listening to D&D podcasts. When I suggested that he uses the gold he earns in-game to upgrade his equipment when he levels up, he said that people don't buy non-magical items and this is the same as spellcasters not actually purchasing their components (I said that spellcasters can just assume they have the material components of spells in their component pouches unless there's a specific cost associated with it).

Is it okay to allow him to have 3 martial weapons as his starting equipment? I'm fairly certain that he's wrong about the not having to buy non-magical items part.

Comment: Are they using a homebrewed race then?

Comment: Yes, the race is essentially just everything a dwarf has and everything an elf has

Comment: And you are okay with them using this homebrewed race?

Comment: Yeah, I allowed pretty much any race/class/background including homebrew because at the end of the day I want my friends to have fun and everyone else has been pretty good at making balanced characters.

Comment: Did everyone else choose two races?

Comment: "You get all the racial bonuses for both races" isn't particularly balanced against standard races.

Comment: We have a dragonborn who was raised by dwarves who did pretty good at balancing out the two races by giving his character all the social abilities of dwarves and the physical bonuses of dragonborns. The rest chose a single race.

Comment: Are you sure its the sage background?

Comment: Do you mean the Noble background?

Comment: I'm sure it's the sage background. The character's backstory is that he's from a noble family and spent years studying to become a sage.

Comment: I think the problem is that we just don't understand how you are determining what is balanced for your table. it's hard to figure out where this question lies when you've already accepted some other things, and I believe that this is ultimately going to be opinion based because it's going to come down to what you feel is balanced.

Comment: For an example of a more balanced attempt at balancing the "half-X, half-Y" character concept mechanically, consider [An Elf And An Orc Had A Little Baby](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/321845/An-Elf-and-an-Orc-Had-a-Little-Baby-Parentage-and-Upbringing-in-DD).

Comment: Side note: I'd encourage you to look at page 6 in your DMG, and talk it over with your players.  It's a really very useful tool for getting feedback on what will keep each of your players happy and engaged.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### You are asking the wrong question.

You are already straying from standard chargen rules.  Specifically, as far as races are concerned, you're already giving your players extra stuff because your players like the feeling of getting extra stuff and you want to make them happy.  This... well, it's a playstyle with an old and honorable tradition, that causes me to suspect that both you and your players are relatively young and/or new to roleplaying.  It's fine.  It is certainly possible to run and enjoy a campaign that involves regularly handing the PCs completely awesome things.  Many before you have done it.

If you do *not* want to run that kind of campaign, I would encourage you to reconsider your houserule on PC races.  Putting blatantly pro-PC houserules like that in place tends to set expectations, going forward, that you'll have difficulty shaking.  Possibly submit proposed houseruled races to this board as a balance question, if you want to give them the flexibility (of building their own) but not the power (of taking too much).

If you *do* want to run that kind of campaign... letting your PC grab a couple of extra martial weapons for his kit isn't going to break anything.  It's not in the rules.  It's not particularly important, though.  It doesn't even matter for the reasons the PC thinks it might matter.  By second level, he'll have plenty of money to buy whatever random martial weapons he wants.  "Enough money to buy martial weapons" is *trivial* to characters who've been adventuring for any real period of time.  So... not legal, but not an issue.

A problem can arise, though, if you only have *one* PC who's trying to grab all of the advantages, and your comments suggest that this is maybe the case.  You have a number of characters who have one race, you have one character who build a reasonably balanced custom race (based partially on Dragonborn, which is generally seen as a bit underpowered) and you have one who wants all of the dwarf stuff and all of the elf stuff and the advantages of the sage background but also he's a noble and wants to use that as justification for things and oh, hey, could he have some extra martial weapons?  Plus he's a bloodhunter... for the extra edge.

My expectation for that sort of situation is that this guy is going to be constantly asking for more/better loot and special exceptions, and probably be something of a spotlight hog.  That can make the game less fun for everyone else at the table, especially if he wants to be not just special, but the *most* special.  This is someone who could very easily turn into a problem player, and that sort of thing is often better handled in setting expectations from the beginning.  I don't have any particular suggestions on *how* to handle it at the moment, however.  If you want to take steps in that direction, I would encourage you to open a separate question with more particulars on the situation.

Answer (score 7):

#### You're the DM. You make the rulings.

The rules could not be more clear about this:

> The D&D rules help you and the other players have a good time, but the rules aren’t in charge. You’re the DM, and you are in charge of the game.

The rules even encourage the DM to change the rules if they want:

> And as a referee, the DM interprets the rules and decides when to abide by them and when to change them.

So you can decide what will be allowed at your table.

#### Take control now, or it will be more difficult later.

I first learned this lesson as a high school teacher. I got my first teaching gig at *22 years old*. I had a student that was less than two years younger than me, and most of my students were no more than 4 or 5 years younger than I was. Before I started, my principal gave me this advice:

> Be firm and take control from the moment you walk in that door. You're young, and they are going to think you will be the cool teacher who will let them get away with stuff. It will start off small, and the more little stuff you let them get away with will make it more and more difficult later to take control of your class room when things get out of hand. Give them an inch, and they will take a mile.

This applies just as well to being a dungeon master. You're the new teacher, and the kids are testing you to see what they can get away with. Have a conversation openly with the whole table and lay down what you as the DM expect of them, which is simply *respect*. Ask that they respect your rulings, admit that you will make mistakes, and explain that you want to try to start everyone on a balanced playing field.

Respectfully establish with them this expectation of respect for your decisions, and encourage them and help them with creating characters within your expectations of balance, *even if that means saying "no, this racial choice isn't appropriate"*.

#### Experience listening to podcasts is not experience playing the game.

I was 20-30 episodes into *Critical Role* when I played my first D&D game. This taught me the rules fairly well. Between my experience listening to the cast play the game, and my experience reading rulebooks, I had a pretty firm grasp on the rules. *But this is all I had*. I had no experience interacting with other players in the context of the game. Listening and watching games being played is not a substitute for real, hands-on experience playing *Dungeons & Dragons*. If it counted as real experience, this experienced player would be working to empower and encourage you as a DM, to build your confidence in making necessary rulings.

#### Okay, done soapboxing, on to the actual character creation.

The Sage background:

> **Equipment**: A bottle of black ink, a quill, a small knife, a letter from a dead colleague posing a question you have not yet been able to answer, a set of common clothes, and *a pouch containing 10 gp*

So you start with 10gp. Now, the Blood Hunter Class:

> You start with the following equipment, in addition to the equipment granted by your background:
>
> - (a) a martial weapon or (b) two simple weapons
> - (a) a light crossbow and 20 bolts or (b) hand crossbow and 20 bolts
> - (a) studded leather armor or (b) scale mail armor
> - an explorer’s pack

It seems pretty clear to me that they cannot take three martial weapons. If you want to stick with this, *then tell them you are going to go with what is written in the class*. That said, if I were the DM, I would be willing to allow them to take a second martial weapon, *instead* of the light crossbow, as light crossbows have the same value as rapiers and scimitars.

Now, you mentioned that this player argued that they should get *extra* gold because of their background. *This is entirely up to you as the DM*. When I moved out and went to college (like your player's character did), my parents sent me the occasional care package with some money in it, but it definitely wasn't enough to buy a sword. Again, and this is a recurring theme at this point, *you have the power to say yes or no to this extra feature*.

#### Spellcasters and Martials are different, and that is okay.

Sure, spellcasters don't have to buy their no-cost components. *But they also can only cast their leveled spells a limited number of times per day*. Ms. Fighter can swing her sword as much as she wants without limitation. They're just different, and that is okay. It seems like a rather obtuse argument to make over a meager 25 gp. You buy it (your second rapier) once and it's good for life. Unless you encounter an ooze.

Again, *it is your world*, and you are right if you want your players to spend their gold on getting new equipment. In my experience *this is standard fare*. I've never played at a table where it was just assumed that mundane equipment was free. You're the DM, you make the call here.

#### Personal Advice on the racial choices, take it or leave it.

Again, I want to empower you to make these decisions for yourself. I don't want to tell you what to do. But I would like to offer a personal recommendation. I would suggest that you forbid the "all the features of two races" race. Permitting homebrew is one thing. Choosing *all* the features of two races is just abusive. Give them an inch, they take a mile, remember? Homebrew is the inch, this is the mile.